# Using custom error page with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to remove `.php` file extentions and add custom error page through `.htaccess` file.

Following is the complete code of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Remove .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]

#Use error500.php file located in the root dir
ErrorDocument 500 /error500
```

The first part to remove extension works but second part does not work. It does not use the `error500.php` file. I have tried adding both with and without .php extention.

Here's the error that I get in the apache error.log

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal
>   redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Could you try add RewriteBase
>
> 2) Add the extension for error500

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /{FOLDER PATH HERE}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Use error500.php file located in the root dir
ErrorDocument 500 {YOUR DIRECTORY HERE}/error500.php
```